# Exclude a vertex and its children in a traversal [Gremlin API]

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

In my graph `product` vertex can have a `composed_of` edge from another `product` vertex.

Now I am trying to exclude a vertex and its children with `composed_of` edge when selecting all vertex with label `product`.

**initially i have the id of the vertex to be excluded, but i dont know how to exclude it and its children when selecting all the `product` vertex in one query.**

Seed db:

```
//add product vertex
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product1').property('pk', 'product1');
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product2').property('pk', 'product2');
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product3').property('pk', 'product3');
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product4').property('pk', 'product4');
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product5').property('pk', 'product5');


//add composed_of edge
g.V('product1').addE('composed_of').to(g.V('product2'))
g.V('product1').addE('composed_of').to(g.V('product3'))
```

now i want to be able to select `product4` and `product5` by excluding product1 and its children with `composed_of` edge.

note: im sorry if this commands wont work with your gremlin console because i first started learning gremlin using cosmosDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
g.V().hasLabel('product').where(
    __.not(coalesce(
         hasId('product1'), 
         __.in('composed_of').hasId('product1')
    ))
)
```